# Is there any macro to get the root directory of the TFS Sourcecontrol in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, post-build-event, visual-studio-macros

Is there any built-in macro to obtain the TFS Sourcecontrol Root directory in Visual Studio?

For example just like $(ProjectDir), I would use $(TFSSourceControlRoot) or something like that?

The reason I need this is to in order to use this path in the xcopy command which I will need as a part of a post build action. Instead of writing something like C:\Source\Scripts, I want to write something like $(TFSSourceControlRootDir)\Source\Scripts.

Comment: You want to include those scripts in the workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the root of the folder structure on the *server*, then you can refer to it as simply `$/`.  However, if you mean the local folder that this is mapped to, there's not a macro for that.  The reason is that you can map any number of folders in the server hierarchy to local disk folders, so there's not necessarily a single root - and there's not necessarily a folder that maps to `$/` at all.

(That said, if you can explain why you need it, there might be alternative suggestions...)

Comment: If you make sure that folder is part of your workspace, you can still use a relative path from the Project directory - such as `$(ProjectDir)\..\..\..\Source\Scripts`.  That's probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

For newer searchers, I found this [build variable page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables), and this is TFS 2015 specific, but it has:

> BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
>
> The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded.
> For example: c:\agent_work\1\s.

Comment: Older documentations states that TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY can be used as well