# command line return the path of the workspace

Tags: vb.net, command-line, wix

Using VS2013 with Add-Ins Express, Designer for Visual Studio WiX Setup Projects
Project properties > Build Events > Post Build Event Command Line...

I wish to return the path of the workspace.  I'm stuck writing the VB script.  This is my attempt the last line returns the same value as set in the first line.

```
  set str1=$(SolutionDir)
  set str2=$(SolutionName)\
  echo.%str1%
  echo.%str2%
  set str1=%str1:str2=%
  echo.%str1%
```

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

similar to this question: [Is there any macro to get the root directory of the TFS Sourcecontrol in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693102/is-there-any-macro-to-get-the-root-directory-of-the-tfs-sourcecontrol-in-visual/25955998?noredirect=1#comment40637679_25955998)

Comment: The code snippet you posted is batch, not VBScript, so which of the two are you trying to use/need help with? If it's VBScript: what does your VBScript code look like? Also, the string replacement (`%str1:str2=%`) does not work as you seem to expect. It removes the *substring* `"str2"` from the value of the *variable* `%str1%`.

Comment: I don't know much about this topic, hence my question.  This is to run at the command-line, sounds like this batch.  The code is to work with file paths, containing \ and . etc.  Could you suggest the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

After Ansgar's hint I figured this out

```
set str1=$(SolutionDir) 
set str1=%str1:$(SolutionName)\=% 
echo.%str1%
```

Comment: the script works as it was designed, but it doesn't return the desired results when the $(SolutionName) is not same as the name of the last folder in $(SolutionDir).  I doubt this approach can work.  I tried used ..\..\Folder name\  but that doesn't seem to work in command line scripts.  Any one have a solution?